# Work with vector of struct with int** as a member

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
int main() {
  int x[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
  struct testCase {
    int** x;
  };
  vector<testCase> v = {{x}};
}
```

`testCase` struct takes a 2D array as its member and I try to declare a vector of such struct. I compile the code with `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cc` and obtain the error

```
test.cc:31:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'vector<testCase>'
  vector<testCase> v = {{x}};
               ^   ~~~~~
```

Since 2D array `x` essentially has type `int**`, I'm not sure why I hit such error in this use case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's wrong: 2d array does not decay into int**.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, to fix the issue, I need to use dynamic array with `new`?

Comment: @xxks-kkk Or use some other type than `int **` -- why do you think you need this specific type anyway? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910). What is your _actual_ goal here?

Comment: Thanks. I'm writing some test cases for a function API with one of the input argument as `int**`; I don't have power to modify such function API.

Comment: @xxks-kkk In that case, the answer to the linked question provides a possible solution. Dynamic allocation is not necessary; pointers can point to stack-allocated values as well.